# Android Bluetooth java.io.IOException: Connection refused

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, bluetooth

I have a problem with android sockets. I am connecting a USB dongle on my PC to an Android phone, a Samsung Galaxy Note II. I am using standard bluetooth sockets creating the socket with createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.

```
btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

The server is listening with listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord.

```
tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,MY_UUID);
```

The pairing happens fine between the client and the server. I have tried with the PC being the server and and the phone being the client and the other way around. In both cases I get the same exception. The logcat is pasted below.

```
04-12 06:14:58.229: D/THINBTCLIENT(2613): ON CREATE got remote device6C:F3:73:47:5B:39

04-12 06:14:58.229: D/THINBTCLIENT(2613): ON CREATE Socket created.

04-12 06:15:01.229: E/THINBTCLIENT(2613): socket connect threw an exception.

04-12 06:15:01.229: E/THINBTCLIENT(2613): java.io.IOException: Connection refused

04-12 06:15:01.229: E/THINBTCLIENT(2613):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)

04-12 06:15:01.229: E/THINBTCLIENT(2613):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:204)

04-12 06:15:01.229: E/THINBTCLIENT(2613):   at com.example.myfirstapp.taskScreen$7.onClick(taskScreen.java:245)
```

I googled and someone said that unpairing and pairing again helps. I tried that too and still the exception persists. If anyone has any idea, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: What's the code at `taskScreen.java:245`?

Comment: Try an insecure socket

Comment: taskScreen.java:245 is socket.connect().

Comment: I don'[t understand what is the reason for the problem. This should logically work but it is continuously giving me this problem.